# 3 Way Quantum Entanglement with a Hadamard Transformed (superposition) Qubit

Tags: quantum-computing, q#, qubit

When running the following operations on 3 qubits:

```
H(qubits[0]);
CNOT(qubits[0], qubits[1]);
CNOT(qubits[0], qubits[2]);
CNOT(qubits[1], qubits[2]);
```

I get these results:
qubit 0 is in a superposition
qubit 1 is the same as qubit 0
qubit 2 is the same as qubit 0 half the time. e.g. superposition-like values.

Why does running CNOT on qubit 2 with both other qubits after running CNOT on qubit 1 with qubit 0 cause qubit 2 to enter a state of superposition between qubit 0 and not qubit 0?

Comment: BTW, there is a brand new [Quantum Computing](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do some quantum computing maths, you will find out that you end up in the following state:

```
|ψ 〉 = (|000〉 + |011〉) / √2
```

This is essentially a superposition between qubit 0 and entangled qubits 1 and 2.

```
|ψ 〉 = |0〉 ⊗ (|00〉 + |11〉) / √2
```

You can do this maths with [IBM QISKit](https://www.qiskit.org) in Python:

```python
from qiskit import QuantumProgram
from math import sqrt
import numpy as np

qp = QuantumProgram()
cname = '3-qubit'
num_qubits = 3
qr = qp.create_quantum_register('qr', num_qubits)
cr = qp.create_classical_register('cr', num_qubits)
qc = qp.create_circuit(cname, [qr], [cr])

qc.h(qr[0])
qc.cx(qr[0], qr[1])
qc.cx(qr[0], qr[2])
qc.cx(qr[1], qr[2])

qc.measure(qr, cr)

results = qp.execute(cname)
print(results.get_counts(cname))
```

This would give you a result similar to the following:

```
{'000': 530, '011': 494}
```

You can also explicitly obtain this state |ψ〉 by taking the unitary matrix of your circuit and applying it to your initial state |000〉, that is a vector `[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`:

```python
results = qp.execute(cname, backend='local_unitary_simulator', shots=1)
data = results.get_data(cname)
u = np.real(data['unitary'] * sqrt(2.0)).astype(int)
psi = np.zeros(2**num_qubits, dtype=np.int_)
psi[0] = 1
u @ psi
```

The result is

```
array([1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

The 0-th entry is |000〉, the 3-rd entry is |011〉.

Comment: Thanks! When writing this question I didn't quite understand how CNOT worked, so I guess I was kind of noob-like with it.

Answer (score 0):

you can see this quantum operation as the bitwise operator quantum in the following,

```
qubits[0]= a
qubits[1] = y
qubits[2] = z
```

and let @ is bitwise operator, 
    x@x = 0 , any p@0 = p

```
qubits[0] = H(a) = x  (superposition state, final x ) 
CNOT(qubits[0], qubits[1]) = CNOT(x,y) = (x, x @ y) = (x, yy)  (final qubits[1]=yy)
CNOT(qubits[0], qubits[2]) = CNOT(x,z) = (x, x @ z) = (x, zz)
CNOT(qubits[1], qubits[2]) = CNOT(yy,zz) = (yy, zz@ yy) = (x@y, x@z@x@y)  = (x@y,z@y) (final qubits[2]=z@y)

(x,y,z) = (0,0,0) ==> (qubits[0],qubits[1],qubits[2]) = (0,0,0)
(x,y,z) = (0,0,1) ==> (qubits[0],qubits[1],qubits[2]) = (0,0,1)
(x,y,z) = (0,1,0) ==> (qubits[0],qubits[1],qubits[2]) = (0,1,1)
(x,y,z) = (0,1,1) ==> (qubits[0],qubits[1],qubits[2]) = (0,1,0)
(x,y,z) = (1,0,0) ==> (qubits[0],qubits[1],qubits[2]) = (1,1,0)
(x,y,z) = (1,0,1) ==> (qubits[0],qubits[1],qubits[2]) = (1,1,1)
(x,y,z) = (1,1,0) ==> (qubits[0],qubits[1],qubits[2]) = (1,0,1)
(x,y,z) = (1,1,1) ==> (qubits[0],qubits[1],qubits[2]) = (1,0,0)
```